# jQuery Slide Out Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slide out tab that currently shows by default on the left side of my page and hides when the button is clicked, then slides out to be visible again when you click it. How can I set the tab to be hidden by default? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<aside id="share-wrapper">
                <div id="sharebutton">></div>

                <div id="share">
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="facebook-share">f</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="twitter-share">t</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="google-share">g</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="insta-share">i</div></div>
                </div>

            </aside>
```

CSS:

```
#share-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:180px;
    margin-top:80px;
}

#share {
    border:thin solid #333;
    border-left:0px;
    border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    width:30px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    height:170px;
}

#sharebutton {
    color:#333;
    border:thin solid #333;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    border-radius:15px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}

#sharebutton:hover { color:#eee; background-color:#333; cursor:pointer; }

#sharebutton.open  {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.share-box,
.share-box img {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}

.facebook-share,
.twitter-share,
.google-share,
.insta-share { width: 100%; height: 100%; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; color:#333; border:thin solid #333; border-radius:15px; margin:10px 0px; background-color:#eee; cursor:pointer;}

.facebook-share:hover,
.twitter-share:hover,
.google-share:hover,
.insta-share:hover { background-color:#333; color:#eee; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sharebutton").click(function () {

        $("#share").toggle("slide");
        if ($("#sharebutton").hasClass("open")) {
            $("#sharebutton").removeClass("open");
        }
        else {
            $("#sharebutton").addClass("open"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cant you just set the div you want hidden to display: none in css? That should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to this. You hide your `share` div and add the `open` class to your `sharebutton`.
So you have the exact same status as you would click the `sharebutton`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#share").hide(); // You set display:none to your share div
    $("#sharebutton").addClass("open"); // You add the open class to the sharebutton

    $("#sharebutton").click(function () {

        $("#share").toggle("slide");
        if ($("#sharebutton").hasClass("open")) {
            $("#sharebutton").removeClass("open");
        }
        else {
            $("#sharebutton").addClass("open"); 
        }
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9hLknfq)